# How can I set up model inheritance in Rails? I've got a class and two subclasses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord

Suppose I'm creating a blog with specific types of posts.

I have a model called an Item. An Item has a name (string) and a link (string) to a source or something. An Item has_and_belongs_to_many :tags (tags are just strings stored in their own database).

I want to extend Items into two different models: Quote and Link.

A Quote is an Item with some content (text) attached to it.

A Link is pretty much the same as an Item.

Both Texts and Links need to have names and links from the Item class, but a Quote has an extra field (the content:text). I'm only giving Link a subclass because it's not supposed to be thought of as a superclass of Quote.

I want to be able to display Links and Quotes on their own pages, and render them differently. I also want to be able to list all Items on the front page, and render them differently (Quotes need to show their content).

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Just a warning: inheritance with ActiveRecord can be notoriously frustrating.

Comment: A less abstract example would be helpful.  How are you relating Foo and Bar to Frob?  Through Single Table Inheritance?

Comment: @MarcTalbot I made it less abstract, hope that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty simple case of ActiveRecord inheritance, and STI (Single Table Inheritance) should suite your needs just fine.

All you really need to do is make sure that your `items` table has all the necessary fields to cover each of its descendants' attributes, plus a type (string) field, which is used internally by ActiveRecord to keep track of the class of each record.

In this case, it looks like you need to add a content (text) field and the type (string) field to the `items` table in the database.

Once you have the right fields, go ahead and subclass `Item`:

```
class Quote < Item
  ...
end
```

etc, etc.

I recommend you use a single ItemsController for both types and keep as much functionality as possible in the parent model, as this generally keeps things cleaner and simpler.

I would add `show` views for each of the subclasses in their own view folder, `app/views/links` for example, so that you can display them differently on their own pages.

I would also add a `app/views/links/_link` partial for each of the types, which Rails will intelligently render when you call `render @item` on the `items#index` page, for example.

```
# items/index.html.haml
- @items.each do |item|
  = render item
```

The above will render `app/views/links/_link.html.haml` for `Link` records and `app/views/quotes/_quote.html.haml` for `Quote` records.

This should make it pretty easy to achieve the functionality you describe.

Comment: This seems to work so far! I added controllers for Link and Quote that only exist to inherit from ItemsController, and added the two types as resources in my config/routes.rb. I'm using view-folder specific partials to render the forms for each one. 
I used :attr_accessible on all the common fields in my models/item.rb, and :attr_accessible on :content in models/quote.rb. However, I'm getting an error when I try to create a new Quote: `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: content`. Any tips?

Comment: Interesting. What you're doing seems quite correct, but to be honest I'm never that specific with `attr_accessible` in my own apps. I always just list all attributes needed by any of the subclasses in the parent class. It does feel a little lazy, but I can't think of a situation in which it would cause any kind of issue. I would double check that you have everything saved, restart your server, and see if the issue resolves itself. If it's definitely not working, I'd just add it in the parent class and move on.